# Which wait will be used until page loads

Tags: java, selenium

Which wait will be used until page loads without any time frame i.e should wait infinitely until page get loaded (selenium,java)

1. driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(***10***, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
2. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,**10**);

both the above syntax having time frame
but webdriver should wait infinitely until page get loaded.

please explain with a example

Comment: Did you try out anything still now? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that page loaded fully you need to check if document state is in complete status, none of these waits for page to load `document.readyState`

Answer (score 1):

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

**Implicit Wait**

The implicit wait will tell to the web driver to wait for certain amount of time before it throws a "No Such Element Exception".
In your example you have declared an implicit wait with the time frame of 10 seconds. It means that if the element is not located on the web page within that time frame, it will throw an exception.

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

**Explicit Wait**
The explicit wait is used to tell the Web Driver to wait for certain conditions (Expected Conditions) or the maximum time exceeded before throwing an "ElementNotVisibleException" exception.

***Your Solution :***

**Fluent Wait**

The fluent wait is used to tell the web driver to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which we want to check the condition before throwing an "ElementNotVisibleException" exception.

The element might load within 10 seconds, 20 seconds or even more then that if we declare an explicit wait of 20 seconds. It will wait till the specified time before throwing an exception. In such scenarios, the fluent wait is the ideal wait to use as this will try to find the element at different frequency until it finds it or the final timer runs out.

**Example :**

> Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
>             .withTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                       .pollingEvery(5,
>   TimeUnit.SECONDS)                         .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutS);

wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)
        {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on your definition of loaded.

Under the hood selenium uses document.readyState in multiple contexts to try and work out if a page is loaded or not.  If you are lucky, your definition of page loaded will match Selenium's attempts to track the status of document.readyState.

Selenium uses the pageLoadTimeout to determine how long it should wait for the page to load (which will include Selenium tracking the state of document.readyState as noted above).  You can modify the default timeout like so:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If your definition of page loaded is not the same as seleniums you will need to perform some additional work, this will usually involve adding explicit waits to look for specific elements that you are interested in interacting with to be visible and in an appropriate state.

The Javadoc for timeouts is available [Here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)